# How to obtain Product Key from Visusal Studio Professional 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I purchased and installed VS 2012 from a download 2 years ago on a 2008R2 server.  I just created a new 2012R2 server and downloaded the VS2013 trial.

I need to get the key from VS2012 on the original server so that I can purchase the VS2013 upgrade. It may or may not have been in the original email but I can’t locate that email. Is there a way to find the key in the old server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used Belarc Advisor in the past. It will show most of your licensing information and  Visual Studios licensing will show up. http://www.belarc.com/free_download.html

Comment: I didn't know about that utility. Really handy.